# How to see a list of all the indexes (including implicit ones) in SQL*Plus?

Tags: sql, indexing, sqlplus

Is there some way to get a list of all the indexes on a particular table using SQL*Plus?

I created a table

```
CREATE TABLE temp(
id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(20));
```

There should be an implicit index created on the primary key (`id`). How can I see that index?

```
SELECT * FROM all_indexes WHERE table_name = 'temp';
```

gives

> no rows selected

Comment: such tables stored in upper-case try select * from all_indexes where table_name = 'TEMP';

Comment: @Michael Pakhantsov, @dcp: thanks! Using upper case, I see the indexes.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`SELECT INDEX_NAME FROM ALL_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table`'

Note:
If you want to limit the search to a specific schema, you can also do:

```
SELECT INDEX_NAME FROM ALL_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table' AND OWNER = 'your_owner'
```

This is useful in situations where you might have the same table name in multiple schemas.

Also, keep in mind that Oracle stores the table names as upper case, so in your example you need to do:

```
select * from all_indexes where table_name = 'TEMP';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * from USER_INDEXES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = UPPER('YourTableName')
```

Comment: That only works if he is logged in as the schema owner for YourTableName.

Answer (score 1):

Please write your table name in upper case

OR

```
SELECT * FROM all_indexes WHERE lower(table_name) = 'temp';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all indexing in a database you can try.

```
use information_schema;
SELECT * FROM statistics;
```

Comment: The OP is using Oracle (in their question they referred to SQL*Plus, which is an Oracle tool).  Your answer won't work for Oracle.